# How to move a div inside another div like google map works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a container that has a certain width and height and overflow hidden.
I have an image inside it with size auto.

What I am trying to achieve is that on mouse move the image should move in all directions so I can see the whole image. Like how it works in google Maps.

This is what I have done so far.

The image is moving only in one direction.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.container').mousemove(function(e) {
    var xLeft = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    if (xLeft <= 100) {
      $('img').css({
        'left': xLeft
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 52px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/52" />
</div>
```

Comment: It moves to both directions in your example, you just capped movement to max 100 px with `if (xLeft <= 100)`

Comment: @Justinas The image size will be bigger than the container. So I need to move it in all direction. But once the image's left become 0 it should not move left: 1. same goes for all the directions.

Could you please help me with the code?

Comment: "*The image size will be bigger than the container*" - You are constraining your image atm though - Have a look over [here](https://css-tricks.com/moving-backgrounds-with-mouse-position/) for some inspiration